# List of DropDowns with selects

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I need to create a list of dropdowns which contains all of the values in the others but points at the selected value depending on ID number.

For example : For ID 1 I have the values:

A B C D E F G

And in dropdowns I need to have for

A : A B C D E F G (but selects A)

on dropdown B I need to have

B : A B C D E F G (but selects B) ... etc

Now here is the code i did :

```
<tbody>
      <!-- foreach($departsreponses as $dr) { -->
      <? foreach($departsreponses as $departsreponse) {?>
          <tr>
              <td>
              <div>

                  <label class="consultation"><?=$departsreponse->N_Depart?></label>                       
                   <select class="modification" name="ndepart">
                <? foreach($departsreponses as $departsreponse) {?>
                        <?
                        echo "<option value='".$departsreponse['N_Depart']."' ".($departsreponse['N_Depart']==$reclamation->N_Depart?' selected ':'').">".$departsreponse['N_Depart']."</option>";
                            ?>
                    <? } ?>

                </select>

                </div>  
              </td>
          </tr>
      <? } ?>
      </tbody>
```

The result i got is : 
A B C D E F G 
But on each dropdown it only selects the A value

This is the view code : i guess the error is probably in here

Please help , it's frustrating when you are at 90% of the result but can't figure it out.

Comment: P.S : the A B C D E F G are just for example and to simplify the explanation

Comment: How is this question related with Joomla?

Comment: Can you Post the values of `$departsreponse['N_Depart']` and `$reclamation->N_Depart`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo "<option value='" . $departsreponse['N_Depart'] . "'" . (($departsreponse['N_Depart'] == $reclamation->N_Depart) ? "> selected " . $departsreponse['N_Depart'] : ">") . "</option>";
```

[HTML  selected Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp)

[Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Similar problem - [ternary operator in echo statement php [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15283353/ternary-operator-in-echo-statement-php)

Comment: srry it doesnt work it gives me empty dropdowns . Thanks for the help btw

Answer (score 0):

You are using same variable name in both for loops.

At line 3

```
<? foreach($departsreponses as $departsreponse) {?>
```

At line 9

```
<? foreach($departsreponses as $departsreponse) {?>
```

Use different reference like

```
<? foreach($departsreponses as $departsreponse1) {?>
```

and

```
<? foreach($departsreponses as $departsreponse2) {?>
```